# How to bufferize a PTS?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, tty, lxc, libvirt

I'm building a system using LXC containers trough libvirt, and I'm trying to record/forward the container's `stdout`.

When creating a new domain, a pseudo-TTY is created in `/dev/pts/*` and I'm able to get the pts attached to a specific LXC container using libvirt's `virsh`: `virsh -c lxc:/// ttyconsole <domain name>`.

Since a pts is a data stream, I'm trying to attach a `screen` in daemon mode as fast as possible after starting the container, using a bash script calling the above `virsh` command then `screen`:

```
CT_PID=$(virsh -c lxc:/// ttyconsole $domain)
screen -dmS my_task $CT_PID
```

But for most tasks the flow of commands is too slow, and some content is streamed trough the pts before `screen` is attached, thus definitely lost.

How can I bufferize the output of the pts device created by libvirt without losing any data ?

Answer (score 0):

For other libvirt drivers you could try using a different `console type=` value like `file`, but the `lxc` driver requires `pty`. Other drivers support `virsh start --paused` but not `lxc`. Possible `virsh start` followed immediately by `virsh pause` will be a bit quicker but it's still racey